# How to shared color palette between multiple subplots?

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, color-palette

I have the following figure:

[image]

The figure is composed by the following code snippet:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
grid = fig.add_gridspec(2, 2)

ax_samples_losses = fig.add_subplot(grid[0, 0:])
ax_samples_losses.set_title('Avg. loss per train sample (epoch 0 excluded)')
for sample_idx, sample_avg_train_loss_history in enumerate(samples_avg_train_loss_history):
    ax_samples_losses.plot(sample_avg_train_loss_history, label='Sample ' + str(sample_idx))
ax_samples_losses.set_title('Avg. loss per train sample (epoch 0 excluded)')
ax_samples_losses.set_xlabel('Epoch')
ax_samples_losses.set_ylabel('Sample avg. loss')
ax_samples_losses.set_xticks(range(1, epochs))
ax_samples_losses.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
ax_samples_losses.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, np.max(samples_avg_train_loss_history), 0.25))
ax_samples_losses.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), prop={'size': 6}) #loc="upper left"
# fig.legend(...)

ax_patches_per_sample = fig.add_subplot(grid[1, 0])
#for sample_idx, sample_patches_count in enumerate(samples_train_patches_count):
#    ax_patches_per_sample.bar(sample_patches_count, label='Sample ' + str(sample_idx))
ax_patches_per_sample.bar(range(0, len(samples_train_patches_count)), samples_train_patches_count, align='center')
ax_patches_per_sample.set_title('Patches per sample')
ax_patches_per_sample.set_xlabel('Sample')
ax_patches_per_sample.set_ylabel('Patch count')
ax_patches_per_sample.set_xticks(range(0, len(samples_train_patches_count)))
ax_patches_per_sample.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, np.max(samples_train_patches_count), 20))
ax_patches_per_sample.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)
```

where

- `samples_train_patches_count` is a simple list with the number of patches per sampled image
- `samples_avg_train_loss_history` is a list of lists in the shape `samples, epochs` (so if viewed as a matrix every row will be a sample and every column will be the loss of that sample over time)

I do believe I need to do both

- shared legend
- shared color palette

The shared legend can be done by using `get_legend_handles_labels()`. However I do not know how to share colors. Both subplots describe different properties of the same thing - the samples. In short I would like to have **Patches per sample** subplot have all the colors **Avg. loss per train sample (epoch 0 excluded)** uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first plot is using standard matplotlib Tab10 discrete color map. We can create a cycler over this colormap, and set one by one the color of each bar:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle

# create a cycler to continously loop over a discrete colormap
cycler = cycle(cm.tab10.colors)

N = 10
x = np.arange(N).astype(int)
y = np.random.uniform(5, 15, N)

f = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(2, 4)
ax0 = f.add_subplot(gs[0, :-1])
ax1 = f.add_subplot(gs[1, :-1])
ax2 = f.add_subplot(gs[:, -1])

for i in x:
    ax0.plot(x, np.exp(-x / (i + 1)), label="Sample %s" % (i + 1))
h, l = ax0.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax1.bar(x, y)
for p in ax1.patches:
    p.set_facecolor(next(cycler))

ax2.axis(False)
ax2.legend(h, l)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

**EDIT** to accommodate comment. To avoid repetitions you should use a colormap. Matplotlib offers many [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). Alternatively, you can also [create your own](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle

N = 50
# create a cycler to continously loop over a discrete colormap
colors = cm.viridis(np.linspace(0, 1, N))

x = np.arange(N).astype(int)
y = np.random.uniform(5, 15, N)

f = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(2, 4)
ax0 = f.add_subplot(gs[0, :-1])
ax1 = f.add_subplot(gs[1, :-1])
ax2 = f.add_subplot(gs[:, -1])

ax1.bar(x, y)

for i in x:
    c = next(cycler)
    ax0.plot(x, np.exp(-x / (i + 1)), color=c, label="Sample %s" % (i + 1))
    ax1.patches[i].set_facecolor(c)
h, l = ax0.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax2.axis(False)
ax2.legend(h, l)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you also add an example with custom colormap, where the first subplot (graph) uses it too. The issue is that once you have more than 10 (`tab10`) or 20 (`tab20`) samples, there is a quite obvious repetition. I just noticed that and will try to change the colormap myself (e.g. with manually generating the colors for the given number of samples).

Comment: Updated answer. You will have to chose an appropriate colormap (or create your own).

Comment: Perfect. Did it with my own colors (using `numpy.random.random_sample()`) but yours looks much better since you are picking colors from an existing colormap that has plenty of colors to choose from.

Comment: @Davide_sd in 2nd example you use `cycler` but never create it.  I tried `colors` but didn't work.  What should I try next?

Comment: @Programming_Learner_DK you are totally right, sorry for that. Here is the variable: `cycler = iter(colors)`